# SQL Server 2005 BULK INSERT's Committed Count

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert, bulk

I use BULK INSERT WITH BATCHSIZE OPTION.
How can I Get Committed Count When the BULK INSERT fail in processing.
like:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BULK INSERT t1 FROM "C:\temp\temp.dat" WITH(BATCHSIZE=1000)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @@rowcount)
END CATCH
```

the `@@rowcount` returned 0

Answer (score 1):

You could count the table rows first into a variable.

```
DECLARE @cntBefore bigint;
SELECT @cntBefore = COUNT(*) FROM t1;
BEGIN TRY
    BULK INSERT t1 FROM "C:\temp\temp.dat" WITH(BATCHSIZE=1000)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @cntAfter bigint;
    SELECT @cntAfter = COUNT(*) FROM t1;
    PRINT 'Imported ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @cntAfter-@cntBefore)
END CATCH
```

Alternatively, use `ROWS_PER_BATCH` to optimise the import, then all the rows will be rolled back.